# Change tab from one tab to another tab as below scenario in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, tabs, silverlight-5.0

Below is the code scenario.

```
<controls:TabControl x:Name="TC"  Background="Black" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,0,8" Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyle1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="2">
        <controls:TabItem Header="TAB1" x:Name="Tab1" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle2}" Foreground="#FFFDFDFD">
            <Grid>
                <local:UC1 x:Name="childUc1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/> 
            </Grid>
        </controls:TabItem>
        <controls:TabItem Header="TAB2" x:Name="Tab2" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle2}" Foreground="White">
            <Grid>
                <local:UC2 Margin="0" Width="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </controls:TabItem>
    </controls:TabControl>
```

Here from the second tab there is one control and from that control there is one button when user click on that button then that would change to first tab. How this possible?

Please anybody help on this issue then that would be a good.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are always going to have two tabs,On the click event of usercontrol, you can do like this,

```
 TC.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: AS I am in the second tab's user control and in that control I am not finding TC means tab control.

Comment: You should be able to find it in the code behind with `this.TC.SelectedIndex = 0, as @Sajeetharan says.